# What is the wrong if i compare string using == operator in java instead of equals() method

Tags: java, string, comparison

As I know

`==` is used to compare references.
`.equals()` is used to compare content.

There is a string pool is available in java.
For example I created a string as follows

`String s ="ABC";` then address for this is suppose 12345

When I use same string i.e "ABC" same string will share in both places. That means addresses for both strings are same.

== is for compare references .In this case address for both strings are same.Then why I need to go for equals() method.Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
public class StringComparison {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s1 ="test";
    String s2 = "test";

    if(s1 == s2)
        System.out.println("BOTH ARE  == ");
    else
        System.out.println("BOTH ARE != ");


    String s3 = new String("test");
    String s4 = new String("test");

    if(s3 == s4)
        System.out.println("BOTH ARE  == ");
    else
        System.out.println("BOTH ARE != ");

  }
}

OUTPUT:
BOTH ARE  == 
BOTH ARE !=
```

But the reference link says `new String("test") == new String("test") ==> false`

Comment: I don't think that `String` object is sharing the same reference, only that it's contents points to that address...so the `String` objects are all different/unique references

Comment: @MadProgrammer address is different from reference ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: If `==` is true (which it is sometimes) then the two `String`s do indeed share the same reference (i.e. are the same object).

Comment: @devnull thank u so much.This is what i am looking for.But because of bad keyword formatting i did not find that link

Comment: @javadeveloper2222 No, they basically mean the same thing...

Comment: @Thilo I would suggest that they are the same Object then, by that extension, they have to have the same content but `new String("Hello") == new String("Hello")` would be `false` as I understand the question, it's more about why `"Hello" == "Hello"` would be false if the text "Hello" has being interned into the String pool

Comment: @Delimanolis check my edit once

Comment: @MadProgrammer can u see my edit once and can u help me

Comment: @java developer 2222  - please check whether the question exists in SOF before posting..

Comment: @MadProgrammer all these people are fast to mark this as duplicate.But no one has the dare to answer it.

Comment: @javadeveloper2222 I thought it was a duplicate at first, but I think it goes a little deeper then why we use `equals`

Comment: This will have something to with how the compiler to deals with `"test"` as opposed to `new String("test")`.  I don't have the knowledge to be 100% correct, but I would surmise that the compiler is producing it's own optimisation in such a way that `"test"` becomes the same object reference, whereas `new String("test")` has to, by it's nature, create a new object each time...

Comment: This link would give a good explanation for it. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Thank u i will refer it.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar String aName = new String("prasad"); is different with String aName = "prasad";

Comment: aName = "prasad" is in string constant pool and new String("prasad") creates a new String object.